# Passing generic EventHandler as function parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, eventhandler

I'm creating a base Object class with some functionality that I would like to use throughout my program. One of of the functions I would like to include is a generic TriggerEvent function that is suppose to do some basic checks before triggering the event passed in:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes the specified event if one of several internal conditions are met:
/// 1. The event is not null
/// 2. The DisableEvents property is not enavled
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventProcedure">Event to execute</param>
/// <param name="e">Event arguments object (or null if none specified)</param>
protected void TriggerEvent(EventHandler<EventArgs> eventProcedure, EventArgs e = null)
{
    if (eventProcedure != null)
    {
        if (!DisableEvents)
        {
            eventProcedure(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm getting into trouble is that I want to be able to pass in generic EventHandlers to this function, so that I can also work with events that may take various forms of the EventArgs object parameter. For example, I have one like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used with the PrintMessage Event
/// </summary>
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MessageEventArgs(string messageText)
    {
        MessageText = messageText;
    }

    public string MessageText { get; private set; }
}
```

And an associated event:

```
public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> PrintMessage;
```

This event will, for example, allow me to pass messages to parent objects. But I also want to be able to use the TriggerEvent function with events that may have other custom Event args objects associated with them:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> SomeEvent;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SomeNormalEvent;
```

and then be able to use the TriggerEvent function to execute any of them:

```
TriggerEvent(PrintMessage, new MessageEventArgs(textToSend));
TriggerEvent(SomeEvent, ExistingCustomEventArgs);
TriggerEvent(SomeNormalEvent);
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to use the TriggerEvent function to invoke, for example, the PrintMessage event that says:

```
Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.EventHandler<TestProject.MessageEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>'
```

How can I modify the TriggerEvent function so that I can use it to check and execute multiple types of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

1. Pass in a delegate instead to execute the event.

`protected void TriggerEvent(Action<EventArgs> eventProcedure, EventArgs e = null)
if (eventProcedure != null && !DisableEvents)
{
    eventProcedure(e);
}`

or just...

`protected void TriggerEvent(Action eventProcedure)
if (eventProcedure != null && !DisableEvents)
{
    eventProcedure();
}`

and used like: `TriggerEvent(() => MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs(...)))`

2. Use a generic method:

`protected void TriggerEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventProcedure, T e = null) where T : EventArgs
if (eventProcedure != null && !DisableEvents)
{
    eventProcedure(this, e);
}`

Comment: Thank you! Your Method #2 was the one I ultimately went with. Works like a charm!